# Adf advanced listView

Tags: java, oracle-adf

any expert adf java web Develop could help .. this list view is returned programmatically from a list , not default collection in a model . when add any button or any action adf component or any panel , it doesn't work . how can i make ot works to make button action works(b1 inside list item) and display popup ?????

```
       <af:button text="button 5" id="b5" action="#{bean2.bttttttttttttest5}" immediate="true"/>

       <af:listView value="#{bean2.filteredDataList}" var="item" shortDesc="wlmwqd"
                    emptyText=""
                    fetchSize="5" id="lv1" >
           <af:listItem id="li1">
               <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1">
                   <af:outputFormatted value="#{item.hotelName}" id="of1"/>


                   <af:outputFormatted value="#{item.price}" id="of2"/>
                   <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2">

                       <af:button text="button 6" id="b1">
                           <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="p1" triggerType="action"/>
                       </af:button>


                       <af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="disabled" id="p1">
                           <af:noteWindow id="nw1">
                               <af:button text="button 2" id="b2"/>
                               <af:button text="button 3" id="b3"/>
                               <af:button text="button 4" id="b4"/>
                           </af:noteWindow>
                       </af:popup>
                   </af:panelGroupLayout>
               </af:panelGroupLayout>
           </af:listItem>
       </af:listView>
   </af:form>
```

and in .java file code of button that get listview from a list :

```
public String bttttttttttttest5() {
    List<Hotel>t=ami.getMaxHotelPrice(200);
    filteredDataList=t;

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the scope of "bean2". In your case it cannot be "request" or "backingBeanScope". Try to make it "viewScope". Also, the button by default has "partialSubmit = true", so you need to put a partialTrigger on the listView.

Here's a code snippet that should work:

```
<af:button text="Run list" id="b1" action="#{viewScope.bean2.bttttttttttttest5}" immediate="true"/>
                    <af:listView value="#{viewScope.bean2.filteredDataList}" var="item" emptyText=""
                                 fetchSize="5" id="lv1" partialTriggers="::b1">
                        <af:listItem id="li1">
                            <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl4">
                                <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" marginBottom="5px" id="gr1">
                                    <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="34%" id="gc1">
                                        <af:outputFormatted value="#{item.hotelName}" id="of1"/>
                                    </af:gridCell>
                                    <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="33%" id="gc2">
                                        <af:outputFormatted value="#{item.price}" id="of2"/>
                                    </af:gridCell>
                                    <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="33%" marginEnd="5px" id="gc3">
                                        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2">
                                            <af:button text="button 6" id="b5">
                                                <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="p1" triggerType="action"/>
                                            </af:button>
                                            <af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="disabled" id="p1">
                                                <af:noteWindow id="nw1">
                                                    <af:button text="button 2" id="b2"/>
                                                    <af:button text="button 3" id="b3"/>
                                                    <af:button text="button 4" id="b4"/>
                                                </af:noteWindow>
                                            </af:popup>
                                        </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                    </af:gridCell>
                                </af:gridRow>
                            </af:panelGridLayout>
                        </af:listItem>
                    </af:listView>
```